# unknown type name namespace in xcode (Awesomium)

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode4

Why does Xcode insist on "Unknown type name 'namespace'" in this C++ header ?!!

Bascially i am trying to use "Awesomium" http://awesomium.com/ sdk in my mac application and i keep getting

"Unknown type name 'namespace" in their hearder files

```
#ifndef __KEYBOARDCODES_H__
#define __KEYBOARDCODES_H__

namespace Awesomium {
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is you application compiling your code as C or C++?

Comment: What is the extension of your implementation files? They should be .mm

Comment: Ok, since there is no source code for the Awesomium framework (that I could find), how exactly did you add the compiled framework into your project?

Comment: @chad, not sure how to tell, sorry i am new to mac osx dev, and xcode i did however follow these instructions to the point http://support.awesomium.com/kb/getting-started/setting-up-on-mac-osx

Comment: @Preception if ou download the sdk it comes with complied libraries and then i followed http://support.awesomium.com/kb/getting-started/setting-up-on-mac-osx

Comment: @Amir - yes I know. I realized this after downloading the SDK to take a peek inside, on my Wintel machine. I will test linking the framework when I get access to my Mac later today. In the meantime, which section of those instructions did you follow? And what version of XCode are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use Awesomium with Objective-C, you will need to use the ANSI C API instead. More information: http://support.awesomium.com/kb/wrappers-integration/ansi-c-api

If you have any other questions, please drop us a line in our support forum: http://support.awesomium.com

Answer (score -2):

Using identifiers with leading double underscores is illegal in user code.

Comment: Sorry, but this is an unrelated comment. Doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: Pretty sure that the compiler is well entitled to reject the code or cause any bad side-effect when encountering such a construct.

Comment: Yes, but you know very well that it is ***not*** the issue here. Why post an answer which is not an answer? Chad's comment is far more useful than this "answer".